# Checkbox и sql?

Tags: php, sql

Здравствуйте, не могу понять, при выставлении галочки, запись в бд не идет. Вот кусочек кода, если нужен полный, скину

```
          <label for="blacklist">
                <i class="fa fa-thumbs-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> Добавить в черный список?:</label><br/>
      <input type="checkbox" <?php if ($a_data['blacklist']=='1') echo 'checked'; ?> name="blacklist" value="<?= ( isset( $a_data['blacklist'] ) ? $a_data['blacklist'] : '' ) ?>"><br/><br/>
      <?= ( isset( $a_error['blacklist'] ) ? '<span style="color: red">'  . $a_error['blacklist'] . '</span><br />' : '' ) ?>
```

Вот ссылка на полный код https://yadi.sk/i/rdTk1dXf3RqPb7

Comment: Для начала отформатируйте код. как вы в нем разбираетесь без форматирования для меня загадка. Кроме того не понятно, зачем вы значение value у чекбокса задаете исходя из значения из БД. Если чекбокс должен быть отмечен, то у него должно быть свойство checked (которое вы и так ставите исходя из данных БД), а вот когда пользователь явно его выберет то к вам на сервер пойдет значение из value, но это значение у вас пустое, если в БД не было 1...  сделайте value всегда 1. И учитесь отлаживать программу. распечатайте значения полученные из браузера и сформированный запрос, посмотрите что не так

Comment: И не используйте расширение mysql, его поддержка скоро будет окончательно прекращена. Ваши программы просто не смогут нигде работать в ближайшем будущем. Используйте PDO или в крайнем случае MySQLi

Comment: Помогло, но как отформатировать код?

Comment: посмотрите любые примеры на php.net том же http://php.net/manual/ru/book.pdo.php  видите, там отступы в начале строк, по которым сразу видно, что внутри какого блока находится. так сразу видно, что от чего зависит